# how to select class where a child has a specific class, in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am working with twitter bootstrap and the jquery validate plugin

I have a form row that looks like:

```
<div class="form_row" >
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="input01">home phone</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="number" class="span4" class="input-xlarge"    id="home_phone"          name="home_phone" value="<?php echo $this->property->home_phone   ?>" rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your home phone." data-original-title="homephone" >
    <input type="number" class="span4" class="input-xlarge" id="cell_phone" name="cell_phone" value="<?php echo $this->property->cell_phone ?>"  rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your cell_phone." data-original-title="cell_phone" >
  </div>
```

after validation, when I look at it in firebug, the inputs with errors are followed by span.error. I would like to select the .control-group divs that have children which are span.error

```
          $(".control-group").filter(function() { return !($(this).children().('span.error'))})
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone get this working?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('span.error').parents('.control-group')
```

This will select any item on the page with the class 'control-group' which has a span anywhere inside of it with a class of 'error'.